# Firebase how to Order by child on js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp, sql-order-by

I can't order a message with timestamp , I tried many ways and it still doesn't work, please help
An arrangement with data like pictures

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdAFC.png)
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us8sG.png)

data:

```
  { chatRoom : {
      "232": {
        "-NKHmBkCihoyRiYABX5O": {
          "createdAtDate": "2022-12-27",
          "createdAtTime": "17:52:49",
          "fromType": 4,
          "message": "message2",
          "readByAdmin": false,
          "readByUser": true,
          "timestamp": 1672131169.174558,
          "user": "tuan do",
          "userId": "232"
        }
      },
      "242": {
        "-NKHm6svnBJhWq321aNv": {
          "createdAtDate": "2022-12-27",
          "createdAtTime": "17:52:29",
          "fromType": 3,
          "message": "message1",
          "readByAdmin": false,
          "readByUser": true,
          "timestamp": 1672131149.252743,
          "user": "solashi 歯科衛生士",
          "userId": "242"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

code : const dbRefAdmin = firebase.database().ref('chatRoom').orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(10)

Answer (score 0):

**A simple answer :**

- Try to use "**orderBy**" instead of **"orderByChild**"
- then "**limit**" instead of "**limitToLast**"

Give a feedback in comment and put your post in *solved* status if the code below solves your problem.

*Official documentation : [order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#web-version-8_2)*

```js
var is_start_load = true;
const dbRefAdmin = firebase.database().ref('chatRoom').orderBy('timestamp').limit(10);
```

Comment: firebase.database(...).ref(...).orderBy is not a function

Comment: i use sdk v7 for this